# how to find cosinus betwen two vector?

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, algebra-precalculus

i have task in linear-algebra.

Condition:
we have triangle angles

```
A(-4,2);
B(-1,6);
C(8,-3);
```

How to find cosinus between BA and BC vectors?

please help :( what is solution for this task?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [dot product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dot_product) gets you just what you want.  The dot product of two vectors $\vec u \cdot \vec v = |\vec u||\vec v|\cos \theta$ where $\theta$ is the angle between the vectors.  So  $\cos \theta =\frac{\vec u \cdot \vec v}{|\vec u||\vec v|}$.  The dot product is calculated by summing the products of the components $\vec {BA} \cdot \vec {BC} = -4 \cdot -1 + 2 \cdot 6=4+12=16$

Comment: $\vec A \cdot \vec B = -3 \cdot 9 + (-4) \cdot (-9)$.

Comment: -4 * -1 = 4; 2 * 6 = 12; ????

4+ 12 = 16;

Comment: @Did:  I was taking $\vec A$ to be the vector from the origin to point $A$.  But now I think we have $\vec {BA}=(-3,-4), \vec {BC}= (9,-9), \vec {BA}\cdot \vec {BC}=-3 \cdot 9+-4 \cdot -9=-27+36=9$

Comment: @GiaNebieridze:  Oops, fixed

Comment: so, what is the final answer?

Comment: @GiaNebieridze:  can you find the length of $\vec {BA}$ and $\vec {BC}$?

Comment: @RossMillikan yes, but this si not answer

Comment: I gave you the dot product.  Just divide it by the product of the lengths to get $\cos \theta$ as shown in the answer.

Comment: @RossMillikan Let me suggest to rename $\vec A$ and $\vec B$ to something like $\vec u$ and $\vec v$, to avoid the confusion with the points $A$ and $B$ which might be a part of the OP's problem at present.

Comment: final answer might be $$\cos \theta = \frac{\sqrt{2}}{10}$$